# How to create a for loop when the variable is in a sentence?

Tags: database, string, python-3.x, dictionary, cursor

I want to create a `for` loop when the `variable` is in a string format.
my code is:

```
for i in range(1,32):
    DEP_RATE = pd.read_sql_query('select  DAYNUM,YYYYMM,sum(DEP_RATE) from ASPM.aspm_qtr where LOCID="ABQ" and DAYNUM = i:"{i}" group by YYYYMM',{i:str(i)},rconn)
```

the error is:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'cursor'

I used this code:

```
for i in range(1,32):
    DEP_RATE = pd.read_sql_query('select  DAYNUM,YYYYMM,sum(DEP_RATE) from ASPM.aspm_qtr where LOCID="ABQ" and DAYNUM = "i" group by YYYYMM',rconn, params={i:str(i)})
```

It hasn't error but doesn't work. the problem is:

```
("Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'i'")
```

Comment: `"bla {} bla".format(i)` is how string formatting works. Not sure, but I think that's what you've been trying there...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a PANDAS question, yes?  I believe it's an argument mismatch with the [read_sql_query API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html).  The function signature is:

```
pandas.read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, chunksize=None)
```

Which roughly says that the first two *positional* arguments are required, and everything else is defaulted or optional.

To make it more obvious, consider putting your core SQL string on a separate line:

```
sql = 'SELECT daynum, ... AND daynum = :i'
for i in range(1, 32):
    DEP_RATE = pd.read_sql_query(sql, {i: str(i)}, rconn)
```

With this formulation, it's more obvious that your arguments do not match the API: your second argument is off.  Perhaps you want (note the additional keyword argument `params`):

```
    DEP_RATE = pd.read_sql_query(sql, rconn, params={i: str(i)})
```

Comment: I used the code but it says ("Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'i'")

Comment: I copy pasted the code from your question, which has a SQL syntax error.  It's `:i`, not `i:`.  See the examples in the [Advanced SQLAlchemy Queries](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html#advanced-sqlalchemy-queries) section of the documentation.

Comment: Look at your very first code block.  You have `i:"{i}"`, and I think you want just `:i`

Comment: The first block is wrong.( it needs also params=). even by adding params the code only with :i doesn't work :(

Comment: Great.  Have you found success now that we've identified some syntax and format errors?

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the code. The correct answer is:

```
DEP_RATE = list(np.zeros((1,1)))*31
for i in range(1,32):
    DEP_RATE[i-1] =np.array(pd.read_sql_query('select  DAYNUM,YYYYMM,sum(DEP_RATE) from ASPM.aspm_qtr where LOCID="ABQ" and DAYNUM = '+str(i)+' group by YYYYMM;',rconn, params={i:str(i)}))
```

Comment: I suggest that you review some of your past questions and [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that solved your problems, that is how the community works, it motivates other members to answer questions and it helps other people with the same problem find answers quicker. That also runs true if you [find a solution by yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it is in fact [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). You have asked seven questions so far and not one of them has been accepted.